# Do (pseudo)varieties closed under wreath product have a name?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, monoid, semidirect-product, wreath-product

Pseudovarieties of finite monoids are often studied in conjunction with the class of regular languages they recognize (a monoid $M$ recognizes a language $L \subseteq A^*$ if $L = h^{-1}(h(L))$ for some morphism $h\colon A^* \to M$).

In that context, a natural property of the pseudovariety is to require that it be closed under wreath products; on the language side, this corresponds for the class to be closed under *cascading*: roughly speaking, the above $L$ cascaded with $L' \subseteq (A \times M)^*$ is the language that contains $w = w_1w_2\cdots w_n \in A^*$ iff $(w_1, h(w_1))(w_2, h(w_1w_2))\cdots(w_n, h(w)) \in L'$.

**Question:** Is there a name for varieties closed under wreath products?  Or for varieties of languages to be closed under cascading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They were called *closed M-varieties* by Samuel Eilenberg [1, p.135], but nowadays most authors seem to call them *(pseudo)-varieties closed under semidirect product*, probably because there are many other closure operators in use: 
(pseudo)-varieties closed under Mal'cev product, under Schützenberger product, under Rhodes expansions, etc.

[1] S. Eilenberg, *Automata, languages, and machines*, Vol. B. Pure and Applied Mathematics, Vol. 59. Academic Press [Harcourt Brace Jovanovich, Publishers], New York-London, 1976. xiii+387 pp.

Comment: Great, that definitely makes sense! Merci!